# convert audio memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, stream

> Hi i want to to convert the memory stream to mp3 and then send it to
>   the client and play it :

here is my asmx code :

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] StartSpeak(string Word)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer synhesizer = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        synhesizer.SelectVoiceByHints(System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceGender.NotSet, System.Speech.Synthesis.VoiceAge.NotSet, 0, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        synhesizer.SetOutputToWaveStream(ms);
        synhesizer.Speak(Word);
    }
    return ms.ToArray();

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis  thank you for replying .Firstly how can i convert the wavestream   to mp3 using using libraries like naudio etc and how to send that audio to run in browser.